# How to swap to the terminal window without exiting the vim editor

Tags: linux

How to swap to the terminal window without exiting the vim editor and to get back to the vim editor file after executing the interrupt command??

Comment: This question is off-topic for this site, try asking at [unix.se] for better answers

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

In vim, type :!sh and hit enter. That will suspend your vim  session and put you in a shell. When you're done there simply type ctrl-d  to get back-to your edit session.